# Marking Points on Raphael

Tags: php, jquery, raphael

So at the moment I have setup a path which effectively creates a graph. All I need to do now is create a hover effect over the points on the path to show the value of the point. How would I go about doing this?

****EDIT****

I am wondering how I could add markers to points on a continual path?
Currently I am looping through PHP and concatenating a variable with more co-ordinates like so:

```
$line .= ' l '.$x.' '.$y;
```

and then

```
echo 'var line = paper.path("M 0 100 '.$line.'")';
```

Seeing as I am using the "l" value for a relative addition to the path, how would I go about adding markers for each point?

Comment: Additional to your path you could add points/circles add each x/y-position. I'm not that into PHP, buy something like this: 
for(...) {
$line .= ' l '.$x.' '.$y;
echo 'var line = paper.path("M 0 100 '.$line.'")';
echo 'var circle = paper.circle($x, $y, 5)';
}

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful! I think the only problem now is that $x values are relative to the previous point, so how would I go about using those $x co-ordinates as absolute values for the circle positions?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display some information above a point (circle), you just have to create a text element in the hover event of the circle and display it. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MpQW9/2/).

**EDIT**

If your x/y values are relative to the previous point, you should cumulate the values beginning with 0.

I don't know exactly how write this in PHP, but something like this:

```
var $absoluteX = 0;
var $absoluteY = 0;
for(...) { 
  $line .= ' l '.$x.' '.$y; 
  echo 'var line = paper.path("M 0 100 '.$line.'")'; 

  $absoluteX += $x; // add the relative change to the previous x value
  $absoluteY += $y;
  echo 'var circle = paper.circle($absoluteX, $absoluteY, 5)'; 
}
```

Comment: Ok that's really helpful, thanks! I have now discovered that my problem is that I can't seem to distribute points relativity evenly across the x axis. If I have a bunch of dates that are 5 months ago, and the range is 6 months ago to today, they all bunch up and look weird. Would you know of any possible way to distribute them evenly according to how many records there are, and also taking into consideration their proposed x value?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ example, for better understanding.

Comment: @Sneaksta - it is of courtesy to up-vote a useful answer, or mark it accepted if it solved your problem. this will also help other users searching a solution for this problem.